# Calling Description & Short Description into phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml

Still learning my feet with magento2. I've found the phtml file I want to call the description and short description from but I've been unable to find the calls needed.

Would it be safe to assume it's the same, different, or a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might depend on exactly what template you are looking to inject this into.
With that said, you should start out by looking into the description template in the Catalog Module:

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/description.phtml`

You are going to need to reference the Catalog Helper to get access to the attribute set.

`$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description')`

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Tyler's answer. To get the short description you can use the following:

```
     <?= $block->getCurrentCategory()->getShortDescription(); ?>
```